# WebStorm debugger not hitting

Tags: webstorm

I have an Angular 8 project. And I am brand new with WebStorm. I can see in previous versions you need to install a Chrome extensions, but as far as I can see this is not needed any more.

First I click "Run" button with the Angular CLI server selected. It executes an `ng serve` as expected and I can start a new browser, navigate to `localhost:4200` and everything is OK.

Then I click the debugger button and i outputs following:

> Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61543/dd15aef1-4ec6-4611-9496-3bd4f8553e31
>   For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
>   Debugger attached.

However breakpoints are not hit. Do I need to setup some extra configurations? When reading documentation it looks like everything should be good from start, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if you are trying to debug NPM script used to start your server (`ng serve` command). This is not a right way to debug Angular application. You need using [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) Run configuration with your server URL (`localhost:4200`) instead:

- build and start your application with `ng serve` (in terminal, or by selecting the pre-created *Angular CLI server* run configuration and pressing **Run**)
- select the *Angular Application* run configuration in configurations dropdown and click **Debug**

Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/angular.html#angular_running_and_debugging_debug for instructions

Comment: Worked! Thanks, appreciated.